# . (dot) command and backspace

Tags: replace, repeated-commands

Say I want to turn this:

```
find(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(), c)
```

into this:

```
find(vec_b->begin(), vec_b->end(), c)
```

That's what I just wanted to do, so I tried this (commands separated by commas):

```
/vec_a, e, rb, a, right, backspace, ->
```

and it did what I wanted it to do which is replace vec_a. with vec_b->. Only problem is when i did `n ciw .` the . only puts -> and not vec_b->. How should I accomplish replacing individual instances of vec_a. with vec_b->?

Comment: you probably want to look at the search & replace command:
`:s/vec_a/vec_b/g` look at `:help :s` for more info

Comment: Eventually recording a macro would be useful here. See `:h complex-repeat`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I only wanted to replace a few occurences of many.

Comment: Another approach: `/vec_a/e` searches for "vec_a" but places cursor at the end of the searched string. Next you do `2sb->` followed by <Esc> which substitutes 2 characters with "b->". From there `n` will match next searched item and `.` will substitute just what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the string you want to replace (`/vec_a\.`), then use `cgn` to replace the string.

You can then replace other instances of `vec_a.` by typing `.` (or `n` to skip).

If you prefer, [vim-visual-star-search](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search) let's you select `vec_a.` visually.